# Problem Setting Up Google Client Java API Calendar Sample for Android

Tags: android, eclipse, mercurial, calendar

******QUESTION WAS EDITED, Please see below**

I am running into a problem when I'm importing a sample project (Calendar-v2-atom-android-sample) into eclipse.

Link of Code: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample/src/com/google/api/client/sample/calendar/android/CalendarAndroidSample.java?repo=samples

Link for Download Setup: http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/calendar-v2-atom-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default

I used Mercurial to clone the project to a local directory. I then imported the file and added the external JARs which are the Google Client Java API (http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup).

I have installed the Maven and Mercurial Plugins for Eclipse.

The first problem I ran into is that beside the root project folder in the Package Explorer of eclipse, there was a message that said "hg status pending...". I fixed this by doing the following: 
Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Mercurial -> uncheck “Use default (built-in) Mercurial executable"

I then set the location of the hg.exe to C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\hg.exe

The problem I'm having now, and which I do not understand is that I am getting little tags on the files in the Package Explorer of eclipse. A little exclamation mark appears by the root project file and yellow tags appear on most of the other files. When I try to compile I get a message that I need to fix errors in the project. I don't know where these errors are.

Here is an image of my workspace:

[image: Calendar Sample Problem]

Please take a look at the tags on the folders.

***IF YOU HAVE TROUBLE SEEING THE IMAGE JUST ZOOM INTO THE PAGE AND IT WILL BE CLEARER.

I would really appreciate anyone's input on this issue.

If anything is unclear please ask and I will try and explain in better.

Cheers.

EDIT---------------------------------------------------------------

This is the problem I'm getting after Merlin answered my first question. Below is a picture of my "Problem" view. It seems to be searching for some JAR files in a repository, but I don't understand why its looking for them there. 
[image]

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Window** -> **Show View** -> **Problems**

This view will provide you with a list of issues that are preventing a successful build

**Update**

You will need to make sure that the appropriate files exist in the paths as listed in the problems window, or adjust the build path to point to the correct location.  Have you done a search on your computer for the jar files it is complainging about?

**Adendum**

To configure the build path, right-click your project folder in eclipse and select

Build Path -> Configure Build Path

Comment: That helped and now I can see the problem but I don't know how to fix it. I will re-edit the question so that it covers the new question. Please see above.

Comment: I have those files on my computuer, but I don't know how to adjust the build path to point to the correct location.

Comment: Thanks Merlin. You're help was great.